# Why isn't this 'Promise Chaining' working?

Tags: javascript, promise

I am trying to understand Promises and Promise Chaining.
As per my understanding, the following code must print 'hello !' to the console. But, it doesn't.
Could anyone explain as to why is this happening and what is the correct way to do it ?

```js
function func01() {
    console.log('func01');
    return new Promise(function(){
        console.log('promise');
        setTimeout(function(){
            console.log('st');
            return 'hello !'
        },5000);
    }).then(function(data){
        console.log('then01');
        return data;
    });
}
function func02() {
    console.log('func02');
    return func01().then(function(data){
        console.log('then02');
        return data;
    })
}
function func03() {
    console.log('func03');
    func02().then(function(data){
        console.log('then03');
        console.log(data);
    });
}
func03();
```

Comment: Hint: the return value of a function invoked via `setTimeout` is ignored. You need to use the parameters provided by the `Promise` constructor (`resolve, reject`) and call `resolve`.

Comment: Maybe reading a bit about how to create promises would be a good start. Questions should demonstrate that you have researched the topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promise should `resolve` into something for it to be passed into then. `setTimeout` is an asynchronous call and the return of that function will not be considered (Per @jcaron). Combining these, here you go:

```js
    function func01() {
        console.log('func01');
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            console.log('promise');
            resolve( 'hello !' )
        }).then(function(data){
            console.log('then01');
            return data;
        });
    }
    function func02() {
        console.log('func02');
        return func01().then(function(data){
            console.log('then02');
            return data;
        })
    }
    function func03() {
        console.log('func03');
        func02().then(function(data){
            console.log('then03');
            console.log(data);
        });
    }
    func03();
```